# How to extract data from different extension format in php

Tags: php

suppose I have some data like *winworldsoft.com, winworldsoft.in, in.pwc.com*

I want to extract the data like winworldsoft in both case *.com* and *.in* and the another data *in.pwc.com* I want to extract only *pwc* and store into database.
I am using the trim function in php but it's not true in some case.

i have writing the code like this

```
$trim_company= rtrim($company_name,".com");
```

Can anybody help me? I would appreciate very much.
if any one write rex for me please.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do it at database level while fetching? If yes, mention the db name / version. If no then please remove the `sql` tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be better to use `str_replace` function:

```
$str = "in.pwc.com";
//$str = "winworldsoft.com";

var_dump(str_replace(['.com', '.in', 'in.'], "", $str));
// ouput: 'pwc'

//'trim' function removes all matched characters from `character mask`:
var_dump(trim($str, ".com .in"));
// ouput: 'pw'   which is not desirable result
```

Comment: can i write code like this
 $company_name = substr($email, strpos($email, "@") + 1); 
$trim_company= trim($company_name, ".com .in .org .net .biz"));

Comment: @SourabhKumar, pay attention to the last part of my post.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're trying to get the domain name from a fqdn witout hostname and without tld, you could split your string by "." and use the second last part:

```
// split by '.'
$fqdnParts = explode('.', $company_name);
// the domain is always the second last part
$company = $fqdnParts[count($fqdnParts) - 2];
```